# Is this abuse of a try/except?

Tags: python-2.7, messaging

This seems like it will do what it 'needs to do' but I get the sense that it's a bad shortcut. I mean we have all these pub-sub libraries for a reason, right?

```
def fakeMessagePasser(myFunction, listOfListeners):
    for obj in listOfListeners:
        try:
            success = getattr(obj, myFunction)()
        except AttributeError:
            handleTheSituationCorrectly()
```

I know that Python prefers to ask forgiveness over permission, but if that's the case why do people ever bother with a 'complex' subscription-based object messaging library in the first place? It seems like the language is set up to handle this innately -- but as often happens, I may just have a big hole in my knowledge that would otherwise inform me as to why this is A Bad Thing.

Is this even good - or put another way, *intended* - application of a try/except? Like, if we were in a game loop and we saw something like this:

```
#incoming pseudocode, not based on anything in particular
for enemy in objectQueue:
    if enemy.hasGoodGuyInSights():
        try:
            enemy.attack()
        except AttributeError: ##maybe this object has no attack method, it just 'follows' or something, who knows why bad guys do anything really
            handleTheSituationCorrectly()
```

This doesn't directly contribute to the death of a family member or anything, but is it good use of a try/except -- or maybe more to the point, is it considered 'pythonic' to do this in this way?

I ask because I feel as though I typically see try/except in place of type-checking: we want to treat objects as if they were of a certain type, and when that fails we handle it correctly. So it seems like there's a difference between using try/except to make sure we iterate over a list or a dict, versus using it to call methods and then failing/ignoring that 'not-a-message' correctly. Right?

Comment: I think that *all* enemy should have an `attack` - that is, I think that the types in the sequence should be either unified or (when iterating) discriminated earlier. This would also prevent legitimate programming errors - such as a missing `attack` - from being hidden. (Also `attack` may "do nothing".)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: I suppose it would depend more on what the better definition of 'explicit' is in Python, then -- do I have objects with placeholder methods that are often and easily overridden BUT do nothing, or do I create objects which only do what they actually do? I think context has a lot to do with this aspect of it, but I like your response nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

What you describe can simulate pub-sub in a limited fashion--good enough I would think for a minimal testing framework.  But you miss out on some essential aspects that you will need in production:

- Asynchronous processing.  In async frameworks such as Twisted, promises and callbacks are used to enforce the relative order of operations but allowing some operations to process while others wait.
- Clustering.  With your method everything must happen within one process/thread.  If you use a broker to do pub-sub you can cluster without changing any of the worker code (assuming the worker code is designed correctly).

Comment: Ahh, yes, I'll admit that these concepts are beyond me. I'm aware enough to know that Python libraries are often written in lower languages like C or lower when people start talking about threads or 'raw performance' or whatever - so the scalability of my example may be part of the reason as well. Hadn't considered that